# Python lagged Fibonacci generator

Tags: python, random, fibonacci

I am trying to write a program in Python to compute a sequence of pseudorandom numbers using the lagged Fibonacci method. I want to generate 2000 numbers in the range (0, 2**32) and then plot `x_i` against `x_i-1`. I have:

```
def lag(s):
    for i in range(k):
        if i is 0:
            out = (s[j-1] + s[k-1]) % m
        elif 0 < i < k - 1:
            s[i] = s[i+1]
        else:
            s[i] = out
            print(s[i])
j, k, m = 7, 10, 2**32

X=[1]

for n in range(2000):
    X.append(lag(X[-1]))
    y = X[:]
    y.append(y[0])
    del y[0]

import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
plt.plot(X, y, '.')
```

When I run the program I get the error

> ```
> out = (s[j-1] + s[k-1]) % m
> TypeError: 'int' object is not subscriptable
> ```

I'm not sure what this error means or how to fix it. Can anyone help?

Comment: when you call `lag(X[-1])` you pass an `int` as `s` instead of a `list`.

Comment: The comment above is right regarding why the error you mention is generated. Concerning your function, it does not return any value, which is a problem. You probably want to add a return s after the for loop. Another thing is that you modify the entire list inside the function. So do you really want to use the append method ? Maybe X = lag(X) would be better ? And finally, you need to be careful that X contains at least max(j, k) values, otherwise you will try to access indices bigger than the size of your list.

Comment: I see no good reason to have `lag` depend on global variables such as `j` and `k`. Why not pass those values as explicit function parameters? It would make your code more modular.

Comment: @Patol75 How do I fix the problem of trying to access indices bigger than the size of my list?

Comment: I think you have at least two possibilities. Either way, your for loop iterates on len(s) instead of k. Either way, you define k based on len(X).